# How to create a table with draft-js-plugin for the latest version?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plugins, draftjs

I just joined and just used the draft js. My manager asked me to create a table with Draftjs-plugins but after I saw that the table-plugin was not there for the latest version, I also read the old table-plugins but didn't understand. Does anyone want to help me to create a table with a draft-js-plugin? maybe someone ever made it?